# apt-get --fix-broken install giving a error

Tags: apt

So today i tried installing xubuntu-desktop and when i was installing it, it gave a error so i tried installing it again and after i installed it again it gave a error

```bsh
root@pc:~# sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
xubuntu-desktop is already the newest version (2.225).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xubuntu-core : Depends: xubuntu-default-settings but it is not going to be installed
 xubuntu-desktop : Depends: xubuntu-default-settings but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: xfce4-quicklauncher-plugin but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

and if i run `apt --fix-broken install` it also gives a error

```bsh
root@pc:~# sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  xubuntu-default-settings
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  xubuntu-default-settings
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 30 not upgraded.
188 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/35.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 205 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 460197 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../xubuntu-default-settings_18.04.6_all.deb ...
Unpacking xubuntu-default-settings (18.04.6) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/xubuntu-default-settings_18.04.6_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/skel/.config/libreoffice/4/user/registrymodifications.xcu', which is also in package zorin-os-default-settings 15.6.6
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/xubuntu-default-settings_18.04.6_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and if i try to uninstall it it also gives a error saying to run `apt --fix-broken install` does anyone know how to fix it?
and i use zorinos which is based on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Looks like that should be logged as a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/zorin-os) against ZorinOS

Comment: @roaima how can i fix it for now?

Comment: Can you `apt remove xubuntu-default-settings` or `apt remove zorinos-default-settings`?

Comment: @roaima yeah i can

Answer (score 1):

Use `force-overwrite` option with `dpkg` :

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/xubuntu-default-settings_18.04.6_all.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

Comment: It gave this error https://pastebin.com/MuPakv1j

Comment: @ARandomPro use `sudo dpkg --configure xubuntu-artwork`